# php: How to access the multiple values of a column of database table using 'mysqli_fetch_assoc()'?

Tags: php

I want to access some of the values of the column 'quantity'.

This is a part of my php code.

```
$quantity_arr = array();
$id_arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
  $quantity_arr[] = $row['quantity'];
  $id_arr[] = $row['book_id'];
}

// when one of the edition is not available
if($quantity_arr[0] == 0 || $quantity_arr[1] == 0){ // checking if the quantity is 0.
  if($quantity_arr[0] == 0){
    $quantity =  $quantity_arr[1];
    $id = $id_arr[1];
  } elseif ($quantity_arr[1] == 0){
    $quantity =  $quantity_arr[0];
    $id = $id_arr[0];
  } else {
    echo "Book not available";
    exit;
  }
```

I am using `$quantity_arr[0]` and  `$quantity_arr[1]` to access the two different values but it's not working. what's the correct way?

Comment: you could use `foreach`

Comment: If this is no longer a problem, or you found the answer via another question, you should delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can access the data like this.

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT *, CASE WHEN quantity > 0 THEN true ELSE false END as available from test_table ORDER by quantity DESC";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    if($row['available']){
        echo $row['book_id'].' - '.$row['quantity'] . '<br />';
    }else{
        echo $row['book_id']." - Book not available".'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT * from test_table ORDER by quantity DESC";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    if($row['quantity'] > 0){
        echo $row['book_id'].' - '.$row['quantity'] . '<br />';
    }else{
        echo $row['book_id']." - Book not available".'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT * from test_table ORDER by quantity DESC";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$items = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $items[] = array('book_id'=> $row['book_id'], 'quantity' => $row['quantity']);
}

//// some codes etc..

foreach($items as $item){
    if($item['quantity'] > 0) { // checking if the quantity is NOT 0.
        echo $item['book_id'].' - '.$item['quantity'] . '<br />';
    } else {
        echo $row['book_id']." - Book not available".'<br />';
        //exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Sorry but thats not the problem. what you are doing is echoing them out one by one but I want them assigned in different variables so that I can access them later.

Comment: Check the last example that before `foreach`. It stored to data in array "$items". You can use that variables later too. I mean `$items[0][book_id], $items[1][book_id], $items[2][quantity]` etc.. That the last example _echoing_ was for you see the results.